# How to execute LINQ query when I have the table`s name stored in a variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Sorry if I didn't explained it right in the title, but here it goes:

I want to do execute a LINQ query, and I have the name of the table to query stored in a variable:

```
string tableName = "SomeTable";

DataContext db = new DataContext();

var vResult = from t in db.tableName
where t.Id = ....
```

Comment: Why do you have the table name in a string?

Comment: I have this tables:

Modification,
Requirement and 
Modification_has_Requirement

some requirements are need to update some tables, others doesn`t

Answer (score 2):

Use Reflection on the DataContext to find a property named `tableName`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at `DataContext.ExecuteQuery<T>`.  However, that still doesn't solve the problem that your results might be different types.